# Error : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' at Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code of swift 2 in xcode 7
when i updated xcode 8 my code showed error.

my code at:

```
      let resultsDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                                    let items: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["list"] as! Array<Swift.Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>


                for i in 0 ..< items.count {
                    let snippetDict = (items[i] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)

                   desired data.


                    we care about.
                    var desiredValuesDict: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
                    desiredValuesDict["title"] =  snippetDict["title"]

                    desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = snippetDict["thumbnail_url"]
                    desiredValuesDict["ID"] =  snippetDict["id"]
```

at line:

```
  let items: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = resultsDict["list"] as! Array<Swift.Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
```

showed error

```
 "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"
```

Also showed same error at:

```
                    desiredValuesDict["title"] =  snippetDict["title"]

                    desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = snippetDict["thumbnail_url"]
                    desiredValuesDict["ID"] =  snippetDict["id"]
```

Please Help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not having rep to leave a comment but...

You should not be using `Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>`. For a dictionary with key as string and value as anything, simply use `[String: Any]`

Bottom line is, you need to post a sample JSON structure for us to better solve your problem